# how to use setInterval and clearInterval properly

Tags: javascript

Here is code that I wrote.

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var day;
  if (date.getDate() < 10) {
    day = "0" + date.getDate();
  } else {
    day = date.getDate();
  }

  var month;
  var tempMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if ( tempMonth < 10){
    month = "0" + tempMonth;
  } else {
    month = tempMonth;
  }
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

jobDate = new Date(2016, 3, 7);
endDate = new Date(2016, 4, 1);
expireInterval = false;

timeoutVar = setTimeout(runJobFromJS,1000);

function runJobFromJS(){
  var strDate = formatDate(jobDate);
  console.log(strDate);

  jobDate = jobDate.addDays(1);

  if (jobDate >= endDate){
    clearInterval(timeoutVar);
  }
}
```

I was expecting that `strDate` will print dates from April 07 till May 01. But it is only printing it once. Why isn't that `setInterval` not working proper

Comment: ...coz setTimeout (Closing it as a typo - you're aware of setInterval)

Comment: It looks like it runs once because you use `setTimeout`; as you mentioned, you should use `setInterval`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author overlooked a mistake in the code while fully acknowledging the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) (executes a function once after an amount of time in milliseconds) instead of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) (continuously executes a function).

The documentation for `setInterval`:

> The setInterval() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval, so you can remove it later by calling clearInterval().

The documentation for `setTimeout`:

> The setTimeout() method of the WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope mixin (and successor to window.setTimeout) sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once after the timer expires.

```
timeoutVar = setInterval(runJobFromJS,1000);//not setTimeout

function runJobFromJS(){
  var strDate = formatDate(jobDate);
  console.log(strDate);

  jobDate = jobDate.addDays(1);

  if (jobDate >= endDate){
    clearInterval(timeoutVar);
  }
}
```

Demo:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var day;
  if (date.getDate() < 10) {
    day = "0" + date.getDate();
  } else {
    day = date.getDate();
  }

  var month;
  var tempMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if ( tempMonth < 10){
    month = "0" + tempMonth;
  } else {
    month = tempMonth;
  }
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

jobDate = new Date(2016, 3, 7);
endDate = new Date(2016, 4, 1);
expireInterval = false;

timeoutVar = setInterval(runJobFromJS,1000);

function runJobFromJS(){
  var strDate = formatDate(jobDate);
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = strDate;
  //console.log(strDate);

  jobDate = jobDate.addDays(1);

  if (jobDate >= endDate){
    clearInterval(timeoutVar);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using [setTimeOut](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) (execute only once) instead of [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds). The **setInterval() method will continue calling the function** until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

--

> The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   after a specified number of milliseconds. Tip: **The function is only
>   executed once.** If you need to repeat execution, use the setInterval()
>   method.

In your case, try:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var day;
  if (date.getDate() < 10) {
    day = "0" + date.getDate();
  } else {
    day = date.getDate();
  }

  var month;
  var tempMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if ( tempMonth < 10){
    month = "0" + tempMonth;
  } else {
    month = tempMonth;
  }
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

jobDate = new Date(2016, 3, 7);
endDate = new Date(2016, 4, 1);
expireInterval = false;

timeoutVar = setInterval(runJobFromJS,1000); //here!

function runJobFromJS(){
  var strDate = formatDate(jobDate);
  console.log(strDate);

  jobDate = jobDate.addDays(1);

  if (jobDate >= endDate){
    clearInterval(timeoutVar);
  }
}
```